# do not show submit for approval button after approved or rejection

Tags: lightning-app-builder

Can Anyone Explain That How do we process lightning app Builder for not showing submit for approval button after approved or reject

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way to hide submit for approval after approved/reject,  Kindly review limitation [here](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdghVUAR/approval-process-removal-of-submit-for-approval-button-after-a-record-is-app). However, you can use new record types, page layouts and workflow rules to conditionally hide the Submit for Approval button. Check more details [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000322175&type=1).